# Any Equivalence between Limit computed via L'Hospital's rule and 0/0 i.e $(\frac{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to c}g(x)})$?

Tags: calculus, limits, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

In Standard Analysis,
Does $$\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to c}g(x)}$$
Given that $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=0$$
Yes, we can get the computed answer for Limit through L'Hospital's rule but what resolution do we have upon this situation about equivalence.
For below function, we can get L = 4 by L'Hospital's rule, but can we say that $$(\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=4)=(\frac{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to c}g(x)}=\frac{0}{0})?$$What do we say of the 2 sides together i.e relation b/w them ? Any Equivalence b/w the 2 sides ? In contrast, equality is indeed possible when the 2 individual limits are non zero.

In Non Standard Analysis (Robinson's Hyperreal Framework), does $$st(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{st(a)}{st(b)}?$$ if $st(a)=0,st(b) = 0$

E.g $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\\ \lim_{x \to 2} \ f(x) = 4$$
Non standard way,
let $$g(x) = x^2-4\\
h(x) = x-2\\$$
dx is an infinitesimal
$$L=st(\frac{g(2+dx)}{h(2+dx)})=st(4+dx)=4$$
Noting that $$\frac{st(g(2+dx))}{st(h(2+dx))}=\frac{M}{N}=\frac{0}{0}=\frac{\lim_{x \to 2}g(x)}{\lim_{x \to 2}h(x)}$$

What can we say about the L, i.e = $$(\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=4)$$, and the 0/0 situation. Any equivalence b/w them ?

In cases where, M and N are non zero,$$st(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{st(a)}{st(b)}=\frac{M}{N}$$ is permissible.

The only case where $$st(\frac{a}{b})\neq\frac{st(a)}{st(b)}$$ is where $$st(b)=0$$

Please Ref - Table 3.3.1, Pg-121, Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach, Howard Jerome Keisler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0/0$ does not exist. We define $+$ and $\times$. Then we define $a-b$ as the unique $c$ such that $a=b+c$, equivalently that $a-b=a+b'$ where $b'$ is the unique additive inverse of $b$, that is $b+b'=0$. Similarly we define $a/b$ as the unique $d$ such that $a=bd$ IF such a unique $d$ exists, equivalently that $a/b=ab''$ if $b''$ is the unique multiplicative inverse of $b$, that is $bb''=1$, IF such a unique $b''$ exists. BUT if $b=0$ then no such $b''$ (unique or not) exists.

Comment: I think this answer might be strengthened if you mentioned that (or explained why) the Robinson's hyperreals don't change anything about this, but the OP didn't ask for that and your answer is certainly correct.

Comment: So when we arrive at 0/0, we leave the case, move on and find other ways to compute the limit. In this sense, our resolution about 0/0, (indeterminacy) is because of our field axioms ? 0/0 happens to be an anomaly here ?

Comment: @user907419 I think the answer to your first question is "no". I could change the field axioms to add "by the way, if I write 0/0, I mean 17". It wouldn't change the fact that limits of the form 0/0 are not *determined* to be any particular value (17 or otherwise), and hence are "indeterminate".